# Php Include in .css

Tags: php, include

I have a menu file "menu_include.php" thats going to be included in 6 pages. I want each element to change per page. Lets say we are in "about.php" i want the "about" to change colors  with no links. How can i do this

Comment: That's what stylesheets are for, right?

Comment: You can't have PHP in a .css file (unless you set server settings to do so).

Comment: http://www.mstudiostalk.com/2008/03/11/pure-css-to-display-the-active-page-in-the-navigation/

Comment: Usually, you have php decide to add a html class to the current "link" in the menu. so If I'm on about.php. Sounds like you need to do a few more tutorials in web development though.

Comment: Don;t be condescending Abe, i've figured it out, its always so hard to try to learn something with comments like yours. Reminds me of the old Director lingo forum. If you cant help please don't comment

Comment: @JoeBodego don't forget to mark it as your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to set a variable before including your menu, something like this.

```
$currentPage = "about"; // change this on each page.
include 'menu_include.php';
```

then in your menu_include, you could do something like this with each link

```
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" <?php if(isset($currentPage) && $currentPage == 'home'){ echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" <?php if(isset($currentPage) && $currentPage == 'about'){ echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" <?php if(isset($currentPage) && $currentPage == 'clients'){ echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" <?php if(isset($currentPage) && $currentPage == 'contact'){ echo ' class="active" '; } ?> >Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then you could style the `.active` class to change colors as you wish..

```
.active {
 background:lime;
}
```

**Edit: To answer your question**, yes you will want to wrap the variable and include in php tags like this.. I didn't put them before, because I assumed you would just put them in your existing php tags.

```
<?php
 $currentPage = "about"; // change this on each page.
 include 'menu_include.php';
?>
```

It sounds like you might want to learn a bit more about php, or even look into using a popular CMS like Wordpress -- http://wordpress.org there are plenty of tutorials/videos that can help you, but unfortunately I can't write ALL of the code for you ;) Trying to help as much as possible.

**Update:** In response to your last question you can add a hover state to your `.onthepage` class.

```
.menu > li > a.onthepage:hover {
  color:#f00;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

This way it won't change when you hover it, I expect that is what you're going for.

Comment: can you do the code for me? i am a bit confused how to code the variable.

Comment: What are you confused about? Lets say you're on about.php you could include it like I did before, then on a contact page for example.. You would say $currentPage = 'contact';

Comment: i would like the complete code to put on each page. i am kinda knew to this . for example is it like this <?php
$currentPage = "about"; // change this on each page.
include 'menu_include.php'; ?>

Comment: Thank you natewiley, i would give it a shot. didn;t mean for you to write the code for me, i just wanted to see how you would wrap it and you did. Thanks again

Comment: I am still have issues but i would try it when i get home in an hour, i would let you know and send you the url.

Comment: Something is wrong with your coding there is a ">" infront of the menu names

Comment: @JoeBodego, There is nothing wrong. I've tested it twice. That is supposed to be there because it is closing off the anchor link. It may look awkward because I purposely tried to space it out for readablity..

Comment: can i send you the files i did, something is not working here.

Comment: Thank you so much it works go here but there is a part b and i promise to leave you alone after this. I would like when you;re at the page that the "hover" state does not work. Go here http://www.aribitar.com/INCLUDE/about.php. Thanks for your help again this eluded me for a long time

Comment: Thank you folks, it all works now. Great job to everyone